# How pass control-param to the picker in alfresco 5?

Tags: javascript, java, alfresco, freemarker

**The problem**

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34872521/1251549) is the answer about extending default `authority.ftl` in alfresco. But when `pickerchildren.get.js` is invoked it has null instead of `argsFilterString`. Also code sources `pickerchildren.get.js` differes from sources in the answer.

**About degugging**

I have aready modified `authority.ftl` to output expression `${field.control.params.filterString}` into html, so this paramer is **not** null and works as expected.

What I really can not understand is `pickerchildren.get.js`, the line `argsFilterString = args['filterString']` always return null. Also there is no special parameters in `args` variable.

So how to pass new controll-param to alfresco picker when alfresco version is 5?

Comment: What exactly you wanted to do with the extra param ? pickerchildren.get.js is different could be because of Alfresco versions.

Comment: I want a filter users by group, see [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34856540/alfresco-limiting-authority-ftl-to-a-group-of-users/34872521#34872521).

Answer (score 1):

Although the date of asking this question is more than 3 years ago, if I faced this issue nowadays too, maybe my solution will help anyway.

There is one more step missing, while implementing this group control.

You have to find in file `/share/components/object-finder/object-finder.js` function `_generatePickerChildrenUrlParams: function ObjectRenderer__generatePickerChildrenUrlParams(searchTerm)` and add into generated URL value of parameter **filterString**:

```
 _generatePickerChildrenUrlParams: function ObjectRenderer__generatePickerChildrenUrlParams(searchTerm)
  {
     var params = "?selectableType=" + this.options.itemType + "&searchTerm=" + encodeURIComponent(searchTerm) + "&size=";
     if (this.options.createNewItemUri !== "")
     {
        params += this.options.maxSearchResults;
     }
     else
     {
        params += this.options.maxChildResults;
     }

     //if filterString control-param has been provided in share-config.xml file
     if ( this.options.filterString ) {
        params += "&filterString="+ this.options.filterString;
     }
     
     .
     .
     .
     .
     return params;
  }
```

It is just one more condition controlling if this parameter is provided in your custom share config.